# Fill html input from sql query using button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have 2 inputs with name and surname, from a database I bring all the values ​​and when pressing a button on the form I would like the inputs to be completed with the data. When there is no data left to show, it should throw a warning. I leave the code of what I have done so far.

```
<?php

function customersData(){
        try {
            $pdo = conect();
            $sql = "Select CTE_LASTNAME,CTE_NAME
                        From customers
                            Where id_store= 1150";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $usuarios = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $customers;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
$data=customersData();
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ficha">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="lastname" class="form-label">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ficha">
        </div>          
    </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnData">Show Data</button>
    </form>
        <script>
            var btnData = document.getElementById("btnData");
            btnData.addEventListener("click",function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Ajax, I added JQuery to simplify it.
Try it, and manage your `id_store` variable.

```auto
<?php

function customersData($id) {
    try {
        $pdo = conect();
        $sql = "Select CTE_LASTNAME,CTE_NAME
                    From customers
                        Where id_store=?";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([$id]);
        return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}

if (!empty($_GET["get_data"])) {
    $data = customersData(intval($_GET["get_data"]));
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit();
}

?>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="lastname" class="form-label">Lastname</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname">
        </div>          
    </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnData">Show Data</button>
    </form>
        <script>
            $("#btnData").click(function (ev) {
                $.get(window.location.href, {
                    "get_data": 1150
                }, function (result) {
                    let obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    $("#name").val(obj.CTE_NAME);
                    $("#lastname").val(obj.CTE_LASTNAME);
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Creeper, thanks for your answer, but I tried it and the button does not complete the inputs, it does nothing.

Comment: In the console show "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (test.php:40)
    at c (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)"

Comment: I see, I forgot the # in the selector for the `btnData`, but I don't think it's the case. The Ajax request is probably responding with something other than JSON. Look at your browser DevTools, what it sends and try to debug it. It works for me if I replace the customersData function with a return just for the output array.

Comment: The error that appears is the following

[Pic Error](https://ibb.co/QP9C5fn).